# Assign a matrix to a subset of a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to assign a matrix to a multi-column subset of a `data.table` but the matrix ends up getting treated as a column vector. For example,

```
dt1 <- data.table(a1=rnorm(5), a2=rnorm(5), a3=rnorm(5))
m1 <- matrix(rnorm(10), ncol=2)
dt1[,c("a1","a2")] <- m1

Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, , c("a1", "a2"), value = c(-0.308851784175091,  :
  2 column matrix RHS of := will be treated as one vector
2: In `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, , c("a1", "a2"), value = c(-0.308851784175091,  :
  Supplied 10 items to be assigned to 5 items of column 'a1' (5 unused)
3: In `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, , c("a1", "a2"), value = c(-0.308851784175091,  :
  2 column matrix RHS of := will be treated as one vector
4: In `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, , c("a1", "a2"), value = c(-0.308851784175091,  :
  Supplied 10 items to be assigned to 5 items of column 'a2' (5 unused)
```

The problem can be solved by first converting `m1` to be another `data.table` object, but I'm curious what the reasonsing is for this error. The above syntax would work if `dt1` were a `data.frame`; what is the architectural rationale for not having it work with `data.table`?

Comment: What you are trying to acheive can be accomplished via `dt1[ , \`:=\`( a1 = m1[,1] , a2 = m1[,2] ) ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `data.frame` is not a `matrix`, nor is a `data.table` a `matrix`. Both `data.frame` and `data.table` objects are `lists`. These are stored very differently, although the indexing can be similar, this is processed under the hood.

Within `[<-.data.frame` splits a matrix-valued `value` into a list with an element for each column.

(The line is `value <- split(value, col(value))`)).

Note also that `[<-.data.frame` will copy the entire data.frame in the process of assigning something to a subset of columns.

`data.table` attempts to avoid this copying, as such `[<-.data.table` should be avoided, as all `<-` methods in `R` make copies.

Within `[<-.data.table`, `[<-.data.frame` will be called if `i` is a matrix, but not if only `value` is.

`data.table` usually likes you to be explicit in ensuring that the types of data match when assigning. This helps avoid any coercion and related copying.

You could, perhaps put in a feature request [here](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) to ensure compatibility, but given your usage is far outside what is recommended, then perhaps the package authors might request you simply use the `data.table` conventions and approaches.

Comment: Thanks @mnel. In this case, what would be the data.table conventions and approaches? Would the preference be to convert `m1` to a `data.table` explicitly and then assign it like I did, or to do something with the `:=` syntax like @SimonO101 outlined in his comment to my original post? If the latter, is there a more compact way to write it?

Answer (score 7):

```
dt1[,c("a1","a2")] <- as.data.table(m1)
```

gives a simple solution but does make a copy.

@Simon O'Hanlon provides a solution in the `data.table`  way:

```
dt1[ , `:=`( a1 = m1[,1] , a2 = m1[,2] ) ]
```

and in my opinion an even better `data.table` solution is provided by @Frank:

```
dt1[,c("a1","a2") := as.data.table(m1)]
```

Comment: You could also include Simon's way as long as you cite him. Generally, comments are treated as "ephemeral", so anything valuable in them ought to end up in posts (questions or answers). One other way: `dt1[,c("a1","a2") := as.data.table(m1)]` https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: I think this approach will also make a copy of `m1` when casting `as.data.table`.