# How to optimize Read and Write to subsections of a matrix in R (possibly using data.table)

Tags: r, performance, data.table

#### TL;DR

> **What is the fastest method in R for reading and writing a subset of
>   columns from a very large matrix. I attempt a solution with data.table
>   but need a fast way to extract a sequence of columns?**
>
> Short Answer: The expensive part of the operation is assignment. Thus the solution is to stick with a matrix and use Rcpp  and C++ to modify the matrix in place. There are two excellent answers below with examples.[for those applying to other problems be sure to read the disclaimers in the solutions!]. Scroll to the bottom of the question for some more lessons learned.

---

This is my first Stack Overflow question- I greatly appreciate your time in taking a look and I apologize if I've left anything out. I'm working on an R package where I have a performance bottleneck from subsetting and writing to portions of a matrix (NB for statisticians the application is updating sufficient statistics after processing each data point).  The individual operations are incredibly fast but the sheer number of them requires it to be as fast as possible.  The simplest version of the idea is a matrix of dimension K by V where K is generally between 5 and 1000 and V can be between 1000 and 1,000,000.

```
set.seed(94253)
K <- 100
V <- 100000
mat <-  matrix(runif(K*V),nrow=K,ncol=V)
```

we then end up performing a calculation on a subset of the columns and adding this into the full matrix.
thus naively it looks like

```
Vsub <- sample(1:V, 20)
toinsert <- matrix(runif(K*length(Vsub)), nrow=K, ncol=length(Vsub))
mat[,Vsub] <- mat[,Vsub] + toinsert
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(mat[,Vsub] <- mat[,Vsub] + toinsert)
```

because this is done so many times it can be quite slow as a result of R's copy-on-change semantics (but see the lessons learned below, modification can actually happen in place in some cricumstances).

For my problem the object need not be a matrix (and I'm sensitive to the difference as outlined here [Assign a matrix to a subset of a data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918946/assign-a-matrix-to-a-subset-of-a-data-table)).  I always want the full column and so the list structure of a data frame is fine. My solution was to use Matthew Dowle's awesome data.table package. The write can be done extraordinarily quickly using set().  Unfortunately getting the value is somewhat more complicated.  We have to call the variables setting with=FALSE which dramatically slows things down.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(mat)  
set(DT, i=NULL, j=Vsub,DT[,Vsub,with=FALSE] + as.numeric(toinsert))
```

Within the set() function using i=NULL to reference all rows is incredibly fast but (presumably due to the way things are stored under the hood) there is no comparable option for j.  @Roland notes in the comments that one option would be to convert to a triple representation (row number, col number, value) and use data.tables binary search to speed retrieval.  I tested this manually and while it is quick, it does approximately triple the memory requirements for the matrix.  I would like to avoid this if possible.

Following the question here: [Time in getting single elemets from data.table and data.frame objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882049/time-in-getting-single-elemets-from-data-table-and-data-frame-objects).  Hadley Wickham gave an incredibly fast solution for a single index

```
Vone <- Vsub[1]
toinsert.one <- toinsert[,1]
set(DT, i=NULL, j=Vone,(.subset2(DT, Vone) + toinsert.one))
```

however since the .subset2(DT,i) is just DT[[i]] without the methods dispatch there is no way (to my knowledge) to grab several columns at once although it certainly seems like it should be possible.  As in the previous question, it seems like since we can overwrite the values quickly we should be able to read them quickly.

Any suggestions?  Also please let me know if there is a better solution than data.table for this problem. I realized its not really the intended use case in many respects but I'm trying to avoid porting the whole series of operations to C.

Here are a sequence of timings of elements discussed- the first two are all columns, the second two are just one column.

```
microbenchmark(mat[,Vsub] <- mat[,Vsub] + toinsert,
              set(DT, i=NULL, j=Vsub,DT[,Vsub,with=FALSE] + as.numeric(toinsert)),
              mat[,Vone] <- mat[,Vone] + toinsert.one,
              set(DT, i=NULL, j=Vone,(.subset2(DT, Vone) + toinsert.one)),
              times=1000L)

Unit: microseconds
                  expr      min       lq   median       uq       max neval
                Matrix   51.970   53.895   61.754   77.313   135.698  1000
            Data.Table 4751.982 4962.426 5087.376 5256.597 23710.826  1000
     Matrix Single Col    8.021    9.304   10.427   19.570 55303.659  1000
 Data.Table Single Col    6.737    7.700    9.304   11.549    89.824  1000
```

---

#### Answer and Lessons Learned:

> Comments identified the most expensive part of the operation as the assignment process. Both solutions give answers based on C code which modify the matrix in place breaking R convention of not modifying the argument to a function but providing a much faster result.
>
> Hadley Wickham stopped by in the comments to note that the matrix modification is actually done in place as long as the object mat is not referenced elsewhere (see http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#modification-in-place).  This points to an interesting and subtle point.  I was performing my evaluations in RStudio.  RStudio as Hadley notes in his book creates an additional reference for every object not within a function.  Thus while in the performance case of a function the modification would happen in place, at the command line it was producing a copy-on-change effect.  Hadley's package pryr has some nice functions for tracking references and addresses of memory.

Comment: +1. Welcome to stack overflow! Great first question with reproducible data, what you tried and what you are trying to achieve. I hope someone can help! My only suggestion would be to be as concise as possible - shorter questions *tend* to garner more views (or at least people reading to the end). Sadly, long ones with detailed descriptions of the problem, where the op has put in a lot of effort sometimes suffer from [**TL;DR**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn't_read)

Comment: Why don't you melt your data.table to long format?

Comment: Thank you @SimonO101 !  I'll see if I can put a tight summary up at the top.

Comment: @Roland Is the suggestion essentially just to have a really long vector?  In principle there is absolutely no reason I couldn't do this but I'm concerned that the time to do the calculations necessary to get the single index would be too high.  More importantly though I think it makes the code less readable as the problem lends itself to a 2-D array.  I should definitely do some timings on it though.

Comment: No, if you melt the data.table (afaik there are efficient reshape functions in the dev version of data.table), you should end up with three columns (rownames, colnames, values). You can then set a key and use binary search. I don't know if that will be faster.

Comment: @Roland Ah I understand.  Thanks.  I did this manually.  The binary search is good but the memory requirements are too high (you end up with three times as many values as when you started).  The matrix is non-sparse so unfortunately I can't even leverage that.  The call is much faster than with=FALSE but not any faster than (for example) writing out all the variables.  I have not looked at the dev version of data.table though- I'll take a look.

Comment: You should point out memory limitations in your question.

Comment: 75% of the execution time in your example is spent on the assignment, so you could make this faster with a fairly simply C function. The args would be `mat`, `Vsub`, and the result of `foo <- mat[, Vsub] + toinsert`. Then you just loop over `Vsub` and `memcpy` each column of `foo` into each respective `mat` column. You'd need to be careful to protect your users though, since you're breaking the functional paradigm by changing one of the inputs to your function.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Thank you for the suggestion.  Could you help clarify something for me as I don't have a great deal of experience with the C interface through R.  The assignment is really expensive in R primarily because of the copy-on-change semantics such that its recreating the entire matrix each time.  However it seems like the same would have to happen in a C function since you are essentially converting the matrix to a representation in C, then converting it back to an R object.

Comment: No conversion is required. R is written in C and you can use the `.Call` interface to directly manipulate R objects in C. There's nothing that _requires_ you make a copy of the objects passed to `.Call`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Fascinating.  Okay this might be exactly the solution then.  You mentioned protecting the user in your original comment but here I actually have the advantage that the function and object being modified is sufficiently embedded in the program that it is never exposed to the end user anyway.  If you would like to put a few lines together that perform an operation like this with timing in a comment I'm happy to approve it as the answer, otherwise I will post about it once I've figured out how to implement it for my particular case.  Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: Unless you're referring to mat in multiple places, subsetting into a matrix is performed in place in R.  See http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#modification-in-place for more details.

Comment: @hadley Thanks for stopping by.  I have read your book (which by the way is fantastic!). I had used address() to confirm that it was copying over.  What I am realizing now is that due to using RStudio refs is actually 2 and thus it was copying but it doesn't copy within a function.  Thanks so much for clarification.  Now I need to figure out whether its changing addresses in my actually application.

Comment: @bstewart yeah, it's a pain to figure out, and one big advantage of using Rcpp is that you can more easily control that behaviour.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Fun with Rcpp:**

You can use [Eigen's Map class](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Map.html) to modify an R object in place.

```
library(RcppEigen)
library(inline)

incl <- '
using  Eigen::Map;
using  Eigen::MatrixXd;
using  Eigen::VectorXi;
typedef  Map<MatrixXd>  MapMatd;
typedef  Map<VectorXi>  MapVeci;
'

body <- '
MapMatd              A(as<MapMatd>(AA));
const MapMatd        B(as<MapMatd>(BB));
const MapVeci        ix(as<MapVeci>(ind));
const int            mB(B.cols());
for (int i = 0; i < mB; ++i) 
{
A.col(ix.coeff(i)-1) += B.col(i);
}
'

funRcpp <- cxxfunction(signature(AA = "matrix", BB ="matrix", ind = "integer"), 
                       body, "RcppEigen", incl)

set.seed(94253)
K <- 100
V <- 100000
mat2 <-  mat <-  matrix(runif(K*V),nrow=K,ncol=V)

Vsub <- sample(1:V, 20)
toinsert <- matrix(runif(K*length(Vsub)), nrow=K, ncol=length(Vsub))
mat[,Vsub] <- mat[,Vsub] + toinsert

invisible(funRcpp(mat2, toinsert, Vsub))
all.equal(mat, mat2)
#[1] TRUE

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(mat[,Vsub] <- mat[,Vsub] + toinsert,
               funRcpp(mat2, toinsert, Vsub))
# Unit: microseconds
#                                  expr    min     lq  median      uq       max neval
# mat[, Vsub] <- mat[, Vsub] + toinsert 49.273 49.628 50.3250 50.8075 20020.400   100
#         funRcpp(mat2, toinsert, Vsub)  6.450  6.805  7.6605  7.9215    25.914   100
```

I think this is basically what @Joshua Ulrich proposed. His warnings regarding breaking R's functional paradigm apply.

I do the addition in C++, but it is trivial to change the function to only do assignment.

Obviously, if you can implement your whole loop in Rcpp, you avoid repeated function calls at the R level and will gain performance.

Comment: Thank you!  This is fantastic.  Clearly the overriding life lesson here is that I need to learn more C++

Answer (score 11):

Here's what I had in mind.  This could probably be much sexier with Rcpp and friends, but I'm not as familiar with those tools.

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>
SEXP addCol(SEXP mat, SEXP loc, SEXP matAdd)
{
  int i, nr = nrows(mat), nc = ncols(matAdd), ll = length(loc);
  if(ll != nc)
    error("length(loc) must equal ncol(matAdd)");
  if(TYPEOF(mat) != TYPEOF(matAdd))
    error("mat and matAdd must be the same type");
  if(nr != nrows(matAdd))
    error("mat and matAdd must have the same number of rows");
  if(TYPEOF(loc) != INTSXP)
    error("loc must be integer");
  int *iloc = INTEGER(loc);

  switch(TYPEOF(mat)) {
    case REALSXP:
      for(i=0; i < ll; i++)
        memcpy(&(REAL(mat)[(iloc[i]-1)*nr]),
               &(REAL(matAdd)[i*nr]), nr*sizeof(double));
      break;
    case INTSXP:
      for(i=0; i < ll; i++)
        memcpy(&(INTEGER(mat)[(iloc[i]-1)*nr]),
               &(INTEGER(matAdd)[i*nr]), nr*sizeof(int));
      break;
    default:
      error("unsupported type");
  }
  return R_NilValue;
}
```

Put the above function in `addCol.c`, then run R CMD SHLIB addCol.c.  Then in R:

```
addColC <- dyn.load("addCol.so")$addCol
.Call(addColC, mat, Vsub, mat[,Vsub]+toinsert)
```

The slight advantage to this approach over Roland's is that this only does the assignment. His function does the addition for you, which is faster, but also means you need a separate C/C++ function for every operation you need to do.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you so much.  This is quite helpful.