# Writing to a large matrix much slower than normal

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose I do this:

```
m <- matrix(0, nrow = 20, ncol = 3)

system.time(m[1, 1:3] <- c(1,1,1))
```

That takes 0 seconds.

Now I do this:

```
m <- matrix(0, nrow = 10000000, ncol = 3)

system.time(m[1, 1:3] <- c(1,1,1))
```

This takes about 0.47 seconds on my system.

I need to fill in a matrix of around 8.5 million rows so at 0.47 seconds each it's not an option. Is there any way around this? Other than creating many smaller sub matrices and rbinding later?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you _need_ to populate the matrix row by row in this manner? (PS: that only takes ~0.03 sec of system time on my system)

Comment: Yes. For every date / item combo I need to perform a rolling regression. The number of dates * the number of items is around 8.5M. I've optimized the regression in Rcpp and it seems that assigning the value is the bottleneck now :(

Even at 0.03 seconds, that's 71 hours.

Comment: So, you are calling your regression function ~8.5M times, and each time it returns a vector of length 3? If so, perhaps consider something like `parSapply`, which would save some time by utilising multiple cores, and could return the entire matrix at once.

Comment: I've rerun your second code block with `microbenchmark`, and it takes, on average, 1.205e-6 seconds. That would come to just over 10 sec for your 8.5M rows. 64-bit R 3.0.2 on Win 8.1, (i4770). If your code/data are sufficiently portable, [fire me an email](http://stackoverflow.com/users/489704/jbaums) and I'll be happy to run it for you and send you the resulting matrix.

Comment: How long will you be thinking about this? More than a day, two? Computer time is cheap. :)

Comment: jbaums thanks for the offer :) But I need to do this multiple times ad-hoc.

Roman I thought about it for about 8 hours, ended up implementing it with Rcpp. Takes 13 seconds now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After starting a new R session:

```
m <- matrix(0, nrow = 10000000, ncol = 3)

system.time(m[1, 1:3] <- c(1,1,1))
# User        System      elapsed 
# 0           0           0 

n <- m
system.time(m[1, 1:3] <- c(1,1,1))
# User        System      elapsed 
# 0.074       0.061       0.135
```

The first time `m` is modified in place. The second time a copy is made since `m` is referred to by `n`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20125947/1412059) might be of interest. However, if you do a rolling regression, you should first look, if it is implemented in some package. If you want to do this in Rcpp, you should do the whole loop in Rcpp and not assign to `m` 8.5M times.